# "ubuntu-support-status" script no longer available in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: package-management, 20.04

The `ubuntu-support-status` command is no longer provided by the `update-manager-core` package. The closest I found is `ubuntu-security-status`:

```
# dpkg --search "ubuntu-*-status*"
update-manager-core: /usr/bin/ubuntu-security-status
```

There are no `man` pages for these commands. So, I cannot compare their usage.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can run `ubuntu-security-status --help` for short usage.

Answer (score 10):

Correct, it is not provided - see [search results on *packages.ubuntu.com*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=ubuntu-support-status).

Why it was removed?
The [changelog](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/u/update-manager/update-manager_20.04.9/changelog) contains the answer:

> update-manager (1:20.04.9) focal; urgency=medium
>
> - Remove ubuntu-support-status as the term support can be confusing and the
>     Supported field has been removed from Launchpad packages. (LP: #1873362)
> - Add ubuntu-security-status - a tool for displaying information about
>     packages installed and the kind of updates which they may or may not
>     receive. (LP: #1873362)
>
> -- Brian Murray   Fri, 17 Apr 2020 15:06:52 -0700

So this command was replaced by `ubuntu-security-status`.

On my 20.04 LTS system its output is as follows:

> ```
> $ ubuntu-security-status 
> 2134 packages installed, of which:
> 1685 receive package updates with LTS until 4/2025
>  449 could receive security updates with ESM Apps until 4/2030
>
> Enable Extended Security Maintenance (ESM Apps) to get 0 security
> updates (so far) and enable coverage of 449 packages.
>
> This machine is not attached to an Ubuntu Advantage subscription.
> See https://ubuntu.com/advantage
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The [manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/check-support-status.1.html) for the command states

> status Provided by: debian-security-support_2020.02.25_all

And the package is available:

> **[Debian security support coverage checker](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/+package/debian-security-support)**
>
> For some Debian packages, it is not feasible to maintain full security
>    support for all use cases through the full distribution release
>    cycle.
>
> This package provides a program to identify installed packages for
>    which support has had to be limited or prematurely ended, and to
>    alert the administrator.
>
> New versions of this package with updated checklists will be provided
>    via standard and/or extended security support.

Installing that will install the command.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am *not* talking about the debian version. I am talking about the specific command (or script) named `ubuntu-support-status`.

Comment: Eh. The command is IN that package and available in Ubuntu. You do know Ubuntu is a derivative of Debian? "Binary package “debian-security-support” in ubuntu focal" The Ubuntu focal part is the interesting part. Not the "debian" in the package name